# Окно с overflow-y

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой, у меня есть есть всплывающее окно, которое не помещается в экране. И при попытке создать бегунок, появляется само окно без бегунка:

[image: Проблема с overflow-y]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close-btn,#bg_popup").click(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (60 * 100));
    $.cookie("popup,bg_popup", "", {
      expires: date
    });
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").hide();
  });



  $("#m-p-yet-reg").click(function() {
    $.cookie("popup,bg_popup", "1", {
      expires: 1
    });
    $("#bg_popup").hide();
  });

  if ($.cookie("popup,bg_popup") == null) {
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").show();
  } else {
    $("#bg_popup,#popup").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#bg_popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

#popup {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 30% auto;
  z-index: 9999999;
  width: 538px;
  background: transparent;
  display: block;
}

.close {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
  color: #ccc;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bg_popup">

</div>
<div id="popup">
  <a class="close" href="#" title="Закрыть" id="close-btn">X</a>

  <div id="main-pop">
    <center>
      <div class="main-pop-head">
        <img src="img/main-pop-head.png" alt="">
        <p class="m-p-h-text-1">Подпишись на нас</p>
        <p class="m-p-h-text-2">Получи 15 страниц нашего платного продукта<br>Эпоха Мудрости за быструю подписку на наш блог</p>
      </div>
      <form action="">
        <input type="email" id="m-p-email" class="main-pop-input-field" placeholder="Ваш e-mail" required="">
        <label for="m-p-email" class="m-p-label-email"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>это поле обязательно для заполнения</label>
        <input type="text" class="main-pop-input-field" placeholder="Ваш город">
        <button class="m-p-get-gift">Получить в дар</button>
        <div class="checks">
          <input id="m-p-check-1" type="checkbox" name="agreement" checked hidden required="" />
          <label for="m-p-check-1"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>Я даю свое согласие на обработку персональных данных и соглашаюсь с условиями и политикой конфиденциальности.
         </label>
          <input id="m-p-check-2" type="checkbox" name="agreement" checked hidden required="" />
          <label for="m-p-check-2"><span class="m-p-req">*</span>Я хочу получать email-письма о мероприятиях  и/или иных услугах
         </label>
        </div>
      </form>
      <form action=>
        <button id="m-p-yet-reg">Я уже зарегистрирован</button>
      </form>
    </center>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А зачем вы в background ставите scroll? Его нужно в #popup

Comment: Т.к мне нужен скрол справа, а не рядом со всплывающим окном, PS там он тоже не появляется

Comment: не понимаю. вам само окно всплывающее, надо прокручивать? тогда так, как я написал. Или вы хотите скролл у самого края экрана, чтобы он прокручивал окно? Нарисуйте, что вам надо.

Comment: Чтобы скролл, у самого края экрана прокручивал окно 
 например как здесь https://ablethink.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B/#open_contactform

Comment: ну, во-первых, этот пример ни разу не достоин подражания. а во-вторых, если он есть - так снимите оттуда css и дело с концом.

Comment: если посмотреть на пример, там создается блок на всю ширину экрана, на него вешается overflow, дальше по середине в нем создается блок для контакта, так и повляется полоса с краю. В вашем случаё у вас ошибка в том, что скролл повешан на backgorund. Сделайте по моёму примеру, все должно раб

Answer (score 1):

В общей сложности, вот так

```js
// Начнём
var $window = $('.window'),
    $windowContent = $('.window-content'),
    $windowBody = $('.window-body'),
    $windowBackground = $('.window-background');

// Для начала мы расчитаем высоту для нашего блока .window-body
// Для этого нам нужно знать, сколько % занимает содержимое окна
var int__pctWindowContent = $('.window-content').outerHeight(true) / $('.window').outerHeight(true);

//  Это значение присваивает для тела окна
$windowBody.css('height', (int__pctWindowContent * 100) + '%');

// Теперь делаем функцию, для переноса значений прокрутки
$windowBackground.scroll(function() {
  var $self = $(this);
  
  var int__selfScrollTop = $self.scrollTop(),
      // Узнаём, сколько % контента прокручено
      int__pctScrollTop = int__selfScrollTop / $windowBody.outerHeight(true);
  
  // Узнаём сколько это от высоты контента
  var int__windowScrollTop = int__pctScrollTop * $windowContent.outerHeight(true);
  
  // Присваиваем это значение для окна
  $window.scrollTop(int__windowScrollTop);
});
```

```css
.window-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.window {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
.window-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.window-content > div + div {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.window-body {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Тут содержимое страницы :)

<div class="window-background">
  <div class="window-body"></div>
  <div class="window">
    <div class="window-content">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque excepturi quibusdam ipsam perferendis nihil voluptate. Voluptatum officia molestiae illo dolorum quibusdam perspiciatis, repellat quas perferendis illum nam eius facere unde.</div>
      <div>Quod saepe quibusdam, enim! Aperiam earum nulla voluptatum nisi, alias ab qui impedit at, sed esse a debitis dignissimos atque! Ipsum laborum, eius doloribus ipsam! Accusamus voluptates provident, recusandae non.</div>
      <div>Odio doloremque voluptatum dolores nesciunt, harum, placeat quisquam nisi rerum quas eos, magni natus, eligendi modi enim a sapiente quibusdam. Qui facere quo non aperiam et mollitia nostrum atque porro.</div>
      <div>Sed nihil odit magnam laudantium aliquam quis accusantium natus odio neque architecto, non laborum commodi saepe asperiores harum officia autem optio id. Placeat quo quia, adipisci dolorem recusandae fugit illo.</div>
      <div>Eius repudiandae, obcaecati, at ad recusandae non nisi sapiente voluptatibus numquam dolor harum tempora et nemo reiciendis sunt vitae quibusdam voluptas! Veritatis nostrum rerum, aliquam numquam, doloremque ratione corporis minima?</div>
      <div>Ad voluptatum culpa ipsum voluptatem ab eius nostrum commodi omnis et, cum dignissimos minus soluta adipisci amet asperiores praesentium modi voluptate est reiciendis itaque suscipit in libero ipsam, perspiciatis laudantium.</div>
      <div>Veritatis corporis consectetur magnam, perferendis unde quae ipsam velit veniam soluta autem vel eum eos provident dolor nostrum dolorum quisquam iste eligendi, natus quam odit saepe! Necessitatibus omnis nam magni.</div>
      <div>A cupiditate ut repudiandae quis pariatur culpa hic atque modi adipisci suscipit laudantium, in, assumenda fugit vitae excepturi, repellat officiis! Facilis fugit explicabo, provident commodi perspiciatis quasi eligendi tempora fugiat.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos nemo porro, non possimus, tempore magnam! Saepe est accusamus repellat, beatae hic deleniti! Iure atque accusamus consectetur quidem reprehenderit sunt voluptatum asperiores fuga earum ex accusantium, doloremque totam vitae.</div>
      <div>Culpa accusamus, iste pariatur laboriosam suscipit magnam iusto dolores quaerat consequatur veniam eum architecto eaque optio illo? Repellat, vel, doloribus. Beatae error suscipit necessitatibus, esse totam minima inventore id libero!</div>
      <div>Architecto, illo cum fuga unde eligendi molestiae dignissimos nihil recusandae veniam. Ipsum dolorum iure, consequuntur beatae. Debitis commodi quaerat quas nobis, soluta, ratione adipisci dignissimos? Eos, sequi eveniet minus fugit.</div>
      <div>Explicabo natus error quia doloribus molestias sapiente id facilis temporibus eveniet earum quis voluptatem ullam, eos cumque blanditiis inventore. Dolorem atque nihil ipsa delectus, perferendis iste obcaecati dolorum incidunt sapiente?</div>
      <div>Blanditiis at minus eius sequi mollitia debitis suscipit, reprehenderit doloribus aliquam consequatur. Nam voluptate laboriosam, consequuntur eius et rem dolore facilis mollitia repudiandae, voluptatum neque obcaecati ratione odit nisi at.</div>
      <div>Quidem ex cumque amet, repellendus aut, dolorum eaque sed officiis repudiandae labore harum voluptatibus neque reiciendis ut impedit cupiditate eveniet earum blanditiis, non optio iste explicabo. Voluptates, veritatis error exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Beatae deserunt accusantium omnis perspiciatis exercitationem illo, architecto nesciunt pariatur quidem minima vel debitis eius possimus dolores dolore assumenda non ducimus qui ab explicabo a, mollitia fuga quisquam! Pariatur, totam!</div>
      <div>Odio rerum explicabo obcaecati quasi eligendi consequuntur sit vitae possimus minus, expedita quidem itaque harum iure aspernatur. Voluptate adipisci ex, beatae, dicta laudantium ipsa quis ducimus repudiandae, doloremque iste, exercitationem!</div>
      <div>Beatae rerum magnam, tenetur numquam officiis adipisci hic excepturi, dolor alias dicta harum quasi quibusdam, vero, placeat impedit natus. Ab quod a nisi dolor, odio quidem mollitia voluptatibus minima doloribus.</div>
      <div>Tenetur corporis itaque ipsum distinctio sint optio ipsa, id perferendis consequuntur quas officiis corrupti inventore, ipsam dolores in eum sed expedita quae aliquid culpa minima aliquam magni aperiam! Obcaecati, ad.</div>
      <div>Fugiat voluptatem officia sint fugit tempora optio nostrum aperiam, doloremque et, alias quidem at atque ut, laboriosam molestiae distinctio! Doloribus beatae sapiente, adipisci aliquid quidem fugit voluptatem nam sint ipsam?</div>
      <div>Aliquam, quidem harum. Magni ab tempora, porro quo architecto, voluptas ipsam maiores, earum facere laboriosam minus excepturi impedit nihil modi voluptatibus, error eius. Quasi, amet, voluptates. Omnis assumenda, explicabo voluptatum.</div>
      <div>Tempore quam inventore et dolorum sequi, id, commodi saepe possimus cumque quaerat dignissimos earum veritatis nesciunt architecto doloremque! Temporibus veritatis laboriosam fugiat recusandae quos quasi eligendi dolores, soluta maiores ad.</div>
      <div>Atque dolorum dolorem alias dolore. Quia praesentium quibusdam ad ea vero assumenda autem quas nulla, architecto, illum maxime? Maxime dolorem at, ut quos velit ipsum! Rem sapiente illo obcaecati eum.</div>
      <div>Minima voluptatem nemo soluta, aliquam aperiam numquam, velit laborum non vero sint, similique atque necessitatibus error minus. Saepe cupiditate accusamus quaerat voluptates? Quia doloribus iste totam neque ea illo inventore!</div>
      <div>Quisquam debitis, quo mollitia a optio vitae atque animi beatae quos laboriosam voluptatem itaque vel odit perspiciatis reiciendis maiores doloremque voluptas enim! Porro labore adipisci, quibusdam, consectetur placeat optio distinctio!</div>
      <div>Sunt obcaecati, aliquam laudantium natus, doloribus suscipit blanditiis nisi assumenda facilis dignissimos distinctio est at delectus neque ad voluptas enim quas vel similique veniam, eaque fugit laborum magni harum! Exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Perspiciatis sapiente similique ut tempora! Similique impedit cum distinctio eum necessitatibus et odit, cumque optio odio eveniet voluptatibus at fugiat deleniti reprehenderit, ad temporibus laboriosam amet blanditiis consequuntur a ipsa.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem omnis aperiam nemo, deserunt odio neque odit non enim possimus ea, magnam libero, dignissimos totam atque, voluptas vel dicta repudiandae! Repellat fugit magnam veniam dolore nostrum deserunt, dolores hic!</div>
      <div>Architecto rerum sapiente voluptate eum omnis vitae error totam cumque quibusdam eveniet in, eligendi ea fugiat? Aliquid, atque. Veniam aliquid perspiciatis voluptates suscipit quidem voluptatibus eius minus, eum possimus facere!</div>
      <div>Consectetur tenetur aspernatur, autem dolorum quia dolor. Deserunt harum ex deleniti veniam amet quaerat similique. Sapiente tempore sunt amet. Error mollitia libero voluptates doloremque ipsam, explicabo modi nostrum atque fugiat.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem sunt asperiores soluta illo optio, qui excepturi, rem sint. Dolores eum repellendus fugit eveniet beatae nulla animi. Eaque incidunt, id quaerat voluptate veniam, fuga rerum unde ipsam earum provident.</div>
      <div>Repellat harum tenetur perspiciatis alias ipsa quisquam? Provident soluta eos unde! Voluptatum praesentium autem labore laudantium itaque perferendis laborum deleniti fugiat suscipit. Ipsam mollitia, commodi eos. Quaerat a voluptas animi!</div>
      <div>Nemo culpa iusto quae aliquam itaque hic, laborum sequi placeat! Unde quo, nesciunt similique nihil sed qui recusandae ratione itaque provident quidem asperiores incidunt cupiditate quisquam, nulla. Impedit totam, quod.</div>
      <div>Nam tempore aliquam, sapiente porro quis enim blanditiis tempora, officia suscipit ea modi hic esse unde expedita consectetur consequuntur eos ex odio ipsa itaque voluptate assumenda quisquam nostrum aspernatur. Expedita.</div>
      <div>Nesciunt autem eos libero quam, voluptatem molestiae molestias quo eius error itaque. Minima quasi iure dolorem officia eaque perspiciatis esse culpa! Possimus blanditiis laborum, vitae iste, quod doloribus similique illo.</div>
      <div>Veritatis repellendus iusto explicabo, ea deleniti molestiae est atque qui inventore reprehenderit! Sapiente vitae omnis quibusdam, necessitatibus. Dolor quibusdam molestiae similique. Possimus sit debitis voluptatibus soluta, nostrum quae error
        esse.</div>
      <div>Nulla quis ut obcaecati, molestias natus deleniti est quia similique odit perferendis nam pariatur iure ab, debitis doloremque repudiandae dignissimos ad doloribus. Vero odit maxime, esse praesentium repellat perferendis pariatur.</div>
      <div>Saepe earum repellat, quaerat animi aperiam optio, illum nesciunt cumque deserunt ut suscipit omnis facilis at maiores veniam ducimus eos eum. Optio perspiciatis minus quam eveniet, maxime praesentium numquam corporis.</div>
      <div>Reiciendis dolore ipsum, omnis. Voluptates odio aspernatur delectus, atque, quos ipsum alias pariatur cum aut blanditiis! Delectus libero nam eaque tenetur eos doloribus architecto voluptate nisi dolorum. Saepe, nihil ullam.</div>
      <div>Voluptates mollitia rem distinctio dicta ipsam aperiam laudantium eius iure incidunt cupiditate eligendi similique earum, ut consectetur ad accusantium, illum quas modi, quo, impedit. A in quo aperiam illum, suscipit.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos praesentium temporibus reprehenderit debitis odio voluptatibus placeat, corporis dolor libero inventore. Magni odio similique, perspiciatis, excepturi nihil voluptatum suscipit. Similique corporis, ut repellendus eligendi tempora sapiente
        nam aut error.</div>
      <div>Ea nihil optio sequi consequuntur! Animi reiciendis, corporis dolore, quaerat ut excepturi, veniam quasi, laudantium explicabo commodi id asperiores sequi minus obcaecati voluptatibus reprehenderit error quis omnis maiores atque? Sit.</div>
      <div>Dolorem dolor, omnis rerum! Magnam quia aliquam id nulla nobis cupiditate hic veritatis autem. Commodi ipsum repellat accusamus sapiente. Et nihil quis fugit non at doloribus dolorum sed laboriosam, commodi.</div>
      <div>Enim odio consequuntur id dolorem, tenetur provident eum labore maxime officia fugit voluptate vero nam, culpa cumque similique iusto molestias autem explicabo pariatur esse minus nulla! Repellendus est quod ratione.</div>
      <div>Provident consectetur itaque placeat, consequatur eum a neque, necessitatibus cumque, excepturi iste incidunt. Consectetur eos similique perferendis illo velit est, dolor doloribus libero dolorem fuga magni praesentium quo iure recusandae?</div>
      <div>Dolores officiis quia fugiat totam cum, doloribus maxime alias enim aliquid doloremque itaque iusto ad reprehenderit illum quae, libero, hic culpa reiciendis vitae eveniet atque rem dignissimos! Ad, iure, accusantium.</div>
      <div>Ipsa sunt adipisci ut eveniet, quisquam temporibus unde, ullam ipsam quam voluptates minima porro deleniti consequatur suscipit tenetur. Quo, iusto beatae quis distinctio in voluptatum possimus ratione culpa praesentium voluptate!</div>
      <div>Sequi tempore labore deserunt laboriosam suscipit odio repudiandae sed necessitatibus cum adipisci architecto rem, nobis optio aperiam consequatur inventore a. Nemo animi, magnam impedit quae repellat sint laudantium inventore nam?</div>
      <div>Ipsam recusandae doloremque alias ratione debitis. Eveniet repellendus doloribus molestiae, reprehenderit. Tempore, reiciendis ducimus ut accusamus molestias voluptatum pariatur magnam id quae est corporis repellendus soluta, consequuntur neque
        eos doloribus!</div>
      <div>Porro, aliquam cumque? Repellendus laudantium non, blanditiis minima quibusdam nobis modi obcaecati at, suscipit molestiae. Laboriosam hic, maiores error eaque eveniet dolor mollitia, ratione quaerat veniam ab repellat culpa cumque?</div>
      <div>Dolore, nisi, perferendis. Placeat, quae? At provident non, temporibus eum perferendis maiores autem natus reprehenderit cum labore veniam recusandae, repellat tempora minima hic enim, debitis iure repellendus magni odio pariatur!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

По вашему примеру из комментариев так

```css
.window-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.window {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    right: 20%;
    margin: 10% 0;
    background-color: white;
}
.window-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.window-content > div + div {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Тут содержимое страницы :)

<div class="window-background">
  <div class="window">
    <div class="window-content">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque excepturi quibusdam ipsam perferendis nihil voluptate. Voluptatum officia molestiae illo dolorum quibusdam perspiciatis, repellat quas perferendis illum nam eius facere unde.</div>
      <div>Quod saepe quibusdam, enim! Aperiam earum nulla voluptatum nisi, alias ab qui impedit at, sed esse a debitis dignissimos atque! Ipsum laborum, eius doloribus ipsam! Accusamus voluptates provident, recusandae non.</div>
      <div>Odio doloremque voluptatum dolores nesciunt, harum, placeat quisquam nisi rerum quas eos, magni natus, eligendi modi enim a sapiente quibusdam. Qui facere quo non aperiam et mollitia nostrum atque porro.</div>
      <div>Sed nihil odit magnam laudantium aliquam quis accusantium natus odio neque architecto, non laborum commodi saepe asperiores harum officia autem optio id. Placeat quo quia, adipisci dolorem recusandae fugit illo.</div>
      <div>Eius repudiandae, obcaecati, at ad recusandae non nisi sapiente voluptatibus numquam dolor harum tempora et nemo reiciendis sunt vitae quibusdam voluptas! Veritatis nostrum rerum, aliquam numquam, doloremque ratione corporis minima?</div>
      <div>Ad voluptatum culpa ipsum voluptatem ab eius nostrum commodi omnis et, cum dignissimos minus soluta adipisci amet asperiores praesentium modi voluptate est reiciendis itaque suscipit in libero ipsam, perspiciatis laudantium.</div>
      <div>Veritatis corporis consectetur magnam, perferendis unde quae ipsam velit veniam soluta autem vel eum eos provident dolor nostrum dolorum quisquam iste eligendi, natus quam odit saepe! Necessitatibus omnis nam magni.</div>
      <div>A cupiditate ut repudiandae quis pariatur culpa hic atque modi adipisci suscipit laudantium, in, assumenda fugit vitae excepturi, repellat officiis! Facilis fugit explicabo, provident commodi perspiciatis quasi eligendi tempora fugiat.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos nemo porro, non possimus, tempore magnam! Saepe est accusamus repellat, beatae hic deleniti! Iure atque accusamus consectetur quidem reprehenderit sunt voluptatum asperiores fuga earum ex accusantium, doloremque totam vitae.</div>
      <div>Culpa accusamus, iste pariatur laboriosam suscipit magnam iusto dolores quaerat consequatur veniam eum architecto eaque optio illo? Repellat, vel, doloribus. Beatae error suscipit necessitatibus, esse totam minima inventore id libero!</div>
      <div>Architecto, illo cum fuga unde eligendi molestiae dignissimos nihil recusandae veniam. Ipsum dolorum iure, consequuntur beatae. Debitis commodi quaerat quas nobis, soluta, ratione adipisci dignissimos? Eos, sequi eveniet minus fugit.</div>
      <div>Explicabo natus error quia doloribus molestias sapiente id facilis temporibus eveniet earum quis voluptatem ullam, eos cumque blanditiis inventore. Dolorem atque nihil ipsa delectus, perferendis iste obcaecati dolorum incidunt sapiente?</div>
      <div>Blanditiis at minus eius sequi mollitia debitis suscipit, reprehenderit doloribus aliquam consequatur. Nam voluptate laboriosam, consequuntur eius et rem dolore facilis mollitia repudiandae, voluptatum neque obcaecati ratione odit nisi at.</div>
      <div>Quidem ex cumque amet, repellendus aut, dolorum eaque sed officiis repudiandae labore harum voluptatibus neque reiciendis ut impedit cupiditate eveniet earum blanditiis, non optio iste explicabo. Voluptates, veritatis error exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Beatae deserunt accusantium omnis perspiciatis exercitationem illo, architecto nesciunt pariatur quidem minima vel debitis eius possimus dolores dolore assumenda non ducimus qui ab explicabo a, mollitia fuga quisquam! Pariatur, totam!</div>
      <div>Odio rerum explicabo obcaecati quasi eligendi consequuntur sit vitae possimus minus, expedita quidem itaque harum iure aspernatur. Voluptate adipisci ex, beatae, dicta laudantium ipsa quis ducimus repudiandae, doloremque iste, exercitationem!</div>
      <div>Beatae rerum magnam, tenetur numquam officiis adipisci hic excepturi, dolor alias dicta harum quasi quibusdam, vero, placeat impedit natus. Ab quod a nisi dolor, odio quidem mollitia voluptatibus minima doloribus.</div>
      <div>Tenetur corporis itaque ipsum distinctio sint optio ipsa, id perferendis consequuntur quas officiis corrupti inventore, ipsam dolores in eum sed expedita quae aliquid culpa minima aliquam magni aperiam! Obcaecati, ad.</div>
      <div>Fugiat voluptatem officia sint fugit tempora optio nostrum aperiam, doloremque et, alias quidem at atque ut, laboriosam molestiae distinctio! Doloribus beatae sapiente, adipisci aliquid quidem fugit voluptatem nam sint ipsam?</div>
      <div>Aliquam, quidem harum. Magni ab tempora, porro quo architecto, voluptas ipsam maiores, earum facere laboriosam minus excepturi impedit nihil modi voluptatibus, error eius. Quasi, amet, voluptates. Omnis assumenda, explicabo voluptatum.</div>
      <div>Tempore quam inventore et dolorum sequi, id, commodi saepe possimus cumque quaerat dignissimos earum veritatis nesciunt architecto doloremque! Temporibus veritatis laboriosam fugiat recusandae quos quasi eligendi dolores, soluta maiores ad.</div>
      <div>Atque dolorum dolorem alias dolore. Quia praesentium quibusdam ad ea vero assumenda autem quas nulla, architecto, illum maxime? Maxime dolorem at, ut quos velit ipsum! Rem sapiente illo obcaecati eum.</div>
      <div>Minima voluptatem nemo soluta, aliquam aperiam numquam, velit laborum non vero sint, similique atque necessitatibus error minus. Saepe cupiditate accusamus quaerat voluptates? Quia doloribus iste totam neque ea illo inventore!</div>
      <div>Quisquam debitis, quo mollitia a optio vitae atque animi beatae quos laboriosam voluptatem itaque vel odit perspiciatis reiciendis maiores doloremque voluptas enim! Porro labore adipisci, quibusdam, consectetur placeat optio distinctio!</div>
      <div>Sunt obcaecati, aliquam laudantium natus, doloribus suscipit blanditiis nisi assumenda facilis dignissimos distinctio est at delectus neque ad voluptas enim quas vel similique veniam, eaque fugit laborum magni harum! Exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Perspiciatis sapiente similique ut tempora! Similique impedit cum distinctio eum necessitatibus et odit, cumque optio odio eveniet voluptatibus at fugiat deleniti reprehenderit, ad temporibus laboriosam amet blanditiis consequuntur a ipsa.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem omnis aperiam nemo, deserunt odio neque odit non enim possimus ea, magnam libero, dignissimos totam atque, voluptas vel dicta repudiandae! Repellat fugit magnam veniam dolore nostrum deserunt, dolores hic!</div>
      <div>Architecto rerum sapiente voluptate eum omnis vitae error totam cumque quibusdam eveniet in, eligendi ea fugiat? Aliquid, atque. Veniam aliquid perspiciatis voluptates suscipit quidem voluptatibus eius minus, eum possimus facere!</div>
      <div>Consectetur tenetur aspernatur, autem dolorum quia dolor. Deserunt harum ex deleniti veniam amet quaerat similique. Sapiente tempore sunt amet. Error mollitia libero voluptates doloremque ipsam, explicabo modi nostrum atque fugiat.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem sunt asperiores soluta illo optio, qui excepturi, rem sint. Dolores eum repellendus fugit eveniet beatae nulla animi. Eaque incidunt, id quaerat voluptate veniam, fuga rerum unde ipsam earum provident.</div>
      <div>Repellat harum tenetur perspiciatis alias ipsa quisquam? Provident soluta eos unde! Voluptatum praesentium autem labore laudantium itaque perferendis laborum deleniti fugiat suscipit. Ipsam mollitia, commodi eos. Quaerat a voluptas animi!</div>
      <div>Nemo culpa iusto quae aliquam itaque hic, laborum sequi placeat! Unde quo, nesciunt similique nihil sed qui recusandae ratione itaque provident quidem asperiores incidunt cupiditate quisquam, nulla. Impedit totam, quod.</div>
      <div>Nam tempore aliquam, sapiente porro quis enim blanditiis tempora, officia suscipit ea modi hic esse unde expedita consectetur consequuntur eos ex odio ipsa itaque voluptate assumenda quisquam nostrum aspernatur. Expedita.</div>
      <div>Nesciunt autem eos libero quam, voluptatem molestiae molestias quo eius error itaque. Minima quasi iure dolorem officia eaque perspiciatis esse culpa! Possimus blanditiis laborum, vitae iste, quod doloribus similique illo.</div>
      <div>Veritatis repellendus iusto explicabo, ea deleniti molestiae est atque qui inventore reprehenderit! Sapiente vitae omnis quibusdam, necessitatibus. Dolor quibusdam molestiae similique. Possimus sit debitis voluptatibus soluta, nostrum quae error
        esse.</div>
      <div>Nulla quis ut obcaecati, molestias natus deleniti est quia similique odit perferendis nam pariatur iure ab, debitis doloremque repudiandae dignissimos ad doloribus. Vero odit maxime, esse praesentium repellat perferendis pariatur.</div>
      <div>Saepe earum repellat, quaerat animi aperiam optio, illum nesciunt cumque deserunt ut suscipit omnis facilis at maiores veniam ducimus eos eum. Optio perspiciatis minus quam eveniet, maxime praesentium numquam corporis.</div>
      <div>Reiciendis dolore ipsum, omnis. Voluptates odio aspernatur delectus, atque, quos ipsum alias pariatur cum aut blanditiis! Delectus libero nam eaque tenetur eos doloribus architecto voluptate nisi dolorum. Saepe, nihil ullam.</div>
      <div>Voluptates mollitia rem distinctio dicta ipsam aperiam laudantium eius iure incidunt cupiditate eligendi similique earum, ut consectetur ad accusantium, illum quas modi, quo, impedit. A in quo aperiam illum, suscipit.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos praesentium temporibus reprehenderit debitis odio voluptatibus placeat, corporis dolor libero inventore. Magni odio similique, perspiciatis, excepturi nihil voluptatum suscipit. Similique corporis, ut repellendus eligendi tempora sapiente
        nam aut error.</div>
      <div>Ea nihil optio sequi consequuntur! Animi reiciendis, corporis dolore, quaerat ut excepturi, veniam quasi, laudantium explicabo commodi id asperiores sequi minus obcaecati voluptatibus reprehenderit error quis omnis maiores atque? Sit.</div>
      <div>Dolorem dolor, omnis rerum! Magnam quia aliquam id nulla nobis cupiditate hic veritatis autem. Commodi ipsum repellat accusamus sapiente. Et nihil quis fugit non at doloribus dolorum sed laboriosam, commodi.</div>
      <div>Enim odio consequuntur id dolorem, tenetur provident eum labore maxime officia fugit voluptate vero nam, culpa cumque similique iusto molestias autem explicabo pariatur esse minus nulla! Repellendus est quod ratione.</div>
      <div>Provident consectetur itaque placeat, consequatur eum a neque, necessitatibus cumque, excepturi iste incidunt. Consectetur eos similique perferendis illo velit est, dolor doloribus libero dolorem fuga magni praesentium quo iure recusandae?</div>
      <div>Dolores officiis quia fugiat totam cum, doloribus maxime alias enim aliquid doloremque itaque iusto ad reprehenderit illum quae, libero, hic culpa reiciendis vitae eveniet atque rem dignissimos! Ad, iure, accusantium.</div>
      <div>Ipsa sunt adipisci ut eveniet, quisquam temporibus unde, ullam ipsam quam voluptates minima porro deleniti consequatur suscipit tenetur. Quo, iusto beatae quis distinctio in voluptatum possimus ratione culpa praesentium voluptate!</div>
      <div>Sequi tempore labore deserunt laboriosam suscipit odio repudiandae sed necessitatibus cum adipisci architecto rem, nobis optio aperiam consequatur inventore a. Nemo animi, magnam impedit quae repellat sint laudantium inventore nam?</div>
      <div>Ipsam recusandae doloremque alias ratione debitis. Eveniet repellendus doloribus molestiae, reprehenderit. Tempore, reiciendis ducimus ut accusamus molestias voluptatum pariatur magnam id quae est corporis repellendus soluta, consequuntur neque
        eos doloribus!</div>
      <div>Porro, aliquam cumque? Repellendus laudantium non, blanditiis minima quibusdam nobis modi obcaecati at, suscipit molestiae. Laboriosam hic, maiores error eaque eveniet dolor mollitia, ratione quaerat veniam ab repellat culpa cumque?</div>
      <div>Dolore, nisi, perferendis. Placeat, quae? At provident non, temporibus eum perferendis maiores autem natus reprehenderit cum labore veniam recusandae, repellat tempora minima hic enim, debitis iure repellendus magni odio pariatur!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

делаю такие вещи так:

```css
.popUp {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.popUp_content-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.popUp-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="popUp">
  <div class="popUp_content-wrap">
    <div class="popUp-content">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque excepturi quibusdam ipsam perferendis nihil voluptate. Voluptatum officia molestiae illo dolorum quibusdam perspiciatis, repellat quas perferendis illum nam eius facere unde.</div>
      <div>Quod saepe quibusdam, enim! Aperiam earum nulla voluptatum nisi, alias ab qui impedit at, sed esse a debitis dignissimos atque! Ipsum laborum, eius doloribus ipsam! Accusamus voluptates provident, recusandae non.</div>
      <div>Odio doloremque voluptatum dolores nesciunt, harum, placeat quisquam nisi rerum quas eos, magni natus, eligendi modi enim a sapiente quibusdam. Qui facere quo non aperiam et mollitia nostrum atque porro.</div>
      <div>Sed nihil odit magnam laudantium aliquam quis accusantium natus odio neque architecto, non laborum commodi saepe asperiores harum officia autem optio id. Placeat quo quia, adipisci dolorem recusandae fugit illo.</div>
      <div>Eius repudiandae, obcaecati, at ad recusandae non nisi sapiente voluptatibus numquam dolor harum tempora et nemo reiciendis sunt vitae quibusdam voluptas! Veritatis nostrum rerum, aliquam numquam, doloremque ratione corporis minima?</div>
      <div>Ad voluptatum culpa ipsum voluptatem ab eius nostrum commodi omnis et, cum dignissimos minus soluta adipisci amet asperiores praesentium modi voluptate est reiciendis itaque suscipit in libero ipsam, perspiciatis laudantium.</div>
      <div>Veritatis corporis consectetur magnam, perferendis unde quae ipsam velit veniam soluta autem vel eum eos provident dolor nostrum dolorum quisquam iste eligendi, natus quam odit saepe! Necessitatibus omnis nam magni.</div>
      <div>A cupiditate ut repudiandae quis pariatur culpa hic atque modi adipisci suscipit laudantium, in, assumenda fugit vitae excepturi, repellat officiis! Facilis fugit explicabo, provident commodi perspiciatis quasi eligendi tempora fugiat.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos nemo porro, non possimus, tempore magnam! Saepe est accusamus repellat, beatae hic deleniti! Iure atque accusamus consectetur quidem reprehenderit sunt voluptatum asperiores fuga earum ex accusantium, doloremque totam vitae.</div>
      <div>Culpa accusamus, iste pariatur laboriosam suscipit magnam iusto dolores quaerat consequatur veniam eum architecto eaque optio illo? Repellat, vel, doloribus. Beatae error suscipit necessitatibus, esse totam minima inventore id libero!</div>
      <div>Architecto, illo cum fuga unde eligendi molestiae dignissimos nihil recusandae veniam. Ipsum dolorum iure, consequuntur beatae. Debitis commodi quaerat quas nobis, soluta, ratione adipisci dignissimos? Eos, sequi eveniet minus fugit.</div>
      <div>Explicabo natus error quia doloribus molestias sapiente id facilis temporibus eveniet earum quis voluptatem ullam, eos cumque blanditiis inventore. Dolorem atque nihil ipsa delectus, perferendis iste obcaecati dolorum incidunt sapiente?</div>
      <div>Blanditiis at minus eius sequi mollitia debitis suscipit, reprehenderit doloribus aliquam consequatur. Nam voluptate laboriosam, consequuntur eius et rem dolore facilis mollitia repudiandae, voluptatum neque obcaecati ratione odit nisi at.</div>
      <div>Quidem ex cumque amet, repellendus aut, dolorum eaque sed officiis repudiandae labore harum voluptatibus neque reiciendis ut impedit cupiditate eveniet earum blanditiis, non optio iste explicabo. Voluptates, veritatis error exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Beatae deserunt accusantium omnis perspiciatis exercitationem illo, architecto nesciunt pariatur quidem minima vel debitis eius possimus dolores dolore assumenda non ducimus qui ab explicabo a, mollitia fuga quisquam! Pariatur, totam!</div>
      <div>Odio rerum explicabo obcaecati quasi eligendi consequuntur sit vitae possimus minus, expedita quidem itaque harum iure aspernatur. Voluptate adipisci ex, beatae, dicta laudantium ipsa quis ducimus repudiandae, doloremque iste, exercitationem!</div>
      <div>Beatae rerum magnam, tenetur numquam officiis adipisci hic excepturi, dolor alias dicta harum quasi quibusdam, vero, placeat impedit natus. Ab quod a nisi dolor, odio quidem mollitia voluptatibus minima doloribus.</div>
      <div>Tenetur corporis itaque ipsum distinctio sint optio ipsa, id perferendis consequuntur quas officiis corrupti inventore, ipsam dolores in eum sed expedita quae aliquid culpa minima aliquam magni aperiam! Obcaecati, ad.</div>
      <div>Fugiat voluptatem officia sint fugit tempora optio nostrum aperiam, doloremque et, alias quidem at atque ut, laboriosam molestiae distinctio! Doloribus beatae sapiente, adipisci aliquid quidem fugit voluptatem nam sint ipsam?</div>
      <div>Aliquam, quidem harum. Magni ab tempora, porro quo architecto, voluptas ipsam maiores, earum facere laboriosam minus excepturi impedit nihil modi voluptatibus, error eius. Quasi, amet, voluptates. Omnis assumenda, explicabo voluptatum.</div>
      <div>Tempore quam inventore et dolorum sequi, id, commodi saepe possimus cumque quaerat dignissimos earum veritatis nesciunt architecto doloremque! Temporibus veritatis laboriosam fugiat recusandae quos quasi eligendi dolores, soluta maiores ad.</div>
      <div>Atque dolorum dolorem alias dolore. Quia praesentium quibusdam ad ea vero assumenda autem quas nulla, architecto, illum maxime? Maxime dolorem at, ut quos velit ipsum! Rem sapiente illo obcaecati eum.</div>
      <div>Minima voluptatem nemo soluta, aliquam aperiam numquam, velit laborum non vero sint, similique atque necessitatibus error minus. Saepe cupiditate accusamus quaerat voluptates? Quia doloribus iste totam neque ea illo inventore!</div>
      <div>Quisquam debitis, quo mollitia a optio vitae atque animi beatae quos laboriosam voluptatem itaque vel odit perspiciatis reiciendis maiores doloremque voluptas enim! Porro labore adipisci, quibusdam, consectetur placeat optio distinctio!</div>
      <div>Sunt obcaecati, aliquam laudantium natus, doloribus suscipit blanditiis nisi assumenda facilis dignissimos distinctio est at delectus neque ad voluptas enim quas vel similique veniam, eaque fugit laborum magni harum! Exercitationem.</div>
      <div>Perspiciatis sapiente similique ut tempora! Similique impedit cum distinctio eum necessitatibus et odit, cumque optio odio eveniet voluptatibus at fugiat deleniti reprehenderit, ad temporibus laboriosam amet blanditiis consequuntur a ipsa.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem omnis aperiam nemo, deserunt odio neque odit non enim possimus ea, magnam libero, dignissimos totam atque, voluptas vel dicta repudiandae! Repellat fugit magnam veniam dolore nostrum deserunt, dolores hic!</div>
      <div>Architecto rerum sapiente voluptate eum omnis vitae error totam cumque quibusdam eveniet in, eligendi ea fugiat? Aliquid, atque. Veniam aliquid perspiciatis voluptates suscipit quidem voluptatibus eius minus, eum possimus facere!</div>
      <div>Consectetur tenetur aspernatur, autem dolorum quia dolor. Deserunt harum ex deleniti veniam amet quaerat similique. Sapiente tempore sunt amet. Error mollitia libero voluptates doloremque ipsam, explicabo modi nostrum atque fugiat.</div>
      <div>Voluptatem sunt asperiores soluta illo optio, qui excepturi, rem sint. Dolores eum repellendus fugit eveniet beatae nulla animi. Eaque incidunt, id quaerat voluptate veniam, fuga rerum unde ipsam earum provident.</div>
      <div>Repellat harum tenetur perspiciatis alias ipsa quisquam? Provident soluta eos unde! Voluptatum praesentium autem labore laudantium itaque perferendis laborum deleniti fugiat suscipit. Ipsam mollitia, commodi eos. Quaerat a voluptas animi!</div>
      <div>Nemo culpa iusto quae aliquam itaque hic, laborum sequi placeat! Unde quo, nesciunt similique nihil sed qui recusandae ratione itaque provident quidem asperiores incidunt cupiditate quisquam, nulla. Impedit totam, quod.</div>
      <div>Nam tempore aliquam, sapiente porro quis enim blanditiis tempora, officia suscipit ea modi hic esse unde expedita consectetur consequuntur eos ex odio ipsa itaque voluptate assumenda quisquam nostrum aspernatur. Expedita.</div>
      <div>Nesciunt autem eos libero quam, voluptatem molestiae molestias quo eius error itaque. Minima quasi iure dolorem officia eaque perspiciatis esse culpa! Possimus blanditiis laborum, vitae iste, quod doloribus similique illo.</div>
      <div>Veritatis repellendus iusto explicabo, ea deleniti molestiae est atque qui inventore reprehenderit! Sapiente vitae omnis quibusdam, necessitatibus. Dolor quibusdam molestiae similique. Possimus sit debitis voluptatibus soluta, nostrum quae error
        esse.</div>
      <div>Nulla quis ut obcaecati, molestias natus deleniti est quia similique odit perferendis nam pariatur iure ab, debitis doloremque repudiandae dignissimos ad doloribus. Vero odit maxime, esse praesentium repellat perferendis pariatur.</div>
      <div>Saepe earum repellat, quaerat animi aperiam optio, illum nesciunt cumque deserunt ut suscipit omnis facilis at maiores veniam ducimus eos eum. Optio perspiciatis minus quam eveniet, maxime praesentium numquam corporis.</div>
      <div>Reiciendis dolore ipsum, omnis. Voluptates odio aspernatur delectus, atque, quos ipsum alias pariatur cum aut blanditiis! Delectus libero nam eaque tenetur eos doloribus architecto voluptate nisi dolorum. Saepe, nihil ullam.</div>
      <div>Voluptates mollitia rem distinctio dicta ipsam aperiam laudantium eius iure incidunt cupiditate eligendi similique earum, ut consectetur ad accusantium, illum quas modi, quo, impedit. A in quo aperiam illum, suscipit.</div>
      <div>Dignissimos praesentium temporibus reprehenderit debitis odio voluptatibus placeat, corporis dolor libero inventore. Magni odio similique, perspiciatis, excepturi nihil voluptatum suscipit. Similique corporis, ut repellendus eligendi tempora sapiente
        nam aut error.</div>
      <div>Ea nihil optio sequi consequuntur! Animi reiciendis, corporis dolore, quaerat ut excepturi, veniam quasi, laudantium explicabo commodi id asperiores sequi minus obcaecati voluptatibus reprehenderit error quis omnis maiores atque? Sit.</div>
      <div>Dolorem dolor, omnis rerum! Magnam quia aliquam id nulla nobis cupiditate hic veritatis autem. Commodi ipsum repellat accusamus sapiente. Et nihil quis fugit non at doloribus dolorum sed laboriosam, commodi.</div>
      <div>Enim odio consequuntur id dolorem, tenetur provident eum labore maxime officia fugit voluptate vero nam, culpa cumque similique iusto molestias autem explicabo pariatur esse minus nulla! Repellendus est quod ratione.</div>
      <div>Provident consectetur itaque placeat, consequatur eum a neque, necessitatibus cumque, excepturi iste incidunt. Consectetur eos similique perferendis illo velit est, dolor doloribus libero dolorem fuga magni praesentium quo iure recusandae?</div>
      <div>Dolores officiis quia fugiat totam cum, doloribus maxime alias enim aliquid doloremque itaque iusto ad reprehenderit illum quae, libero, hic culpa reiciendis vitae eveniet atque rem dignissimos! Ad, iure, accusantium.</div>
      <div>Ipsa sunt adipisci ut eveniet, quisquam temporibus unde, ullam ipsam quam voluptates minima porro deleniti consequatur suscipit tenetur. Quo, iusto beatae quis distinctio in voluptatum possimus ratione culpa praesentium voluptate!</div>
      <div>Sequi tempore labore deserunt laboriosam suscipit odio repudiandae sed necessitatibus cum adipisci architecto rem, nobis optio aperiam consequatur inventore a. Nemo animi, magnam impedit quae repellat sint laudantium inventore nam?</div>
      <div>Ipsam recusandae doloremque alias ratione debitis. Eveniet repellendus doloribus molestiae, reprehenderit. Tempore, reiciendis ducimus ut accusamus molestias voluptatum pariatur magnam id quae est corporis repellendus soluta, consequuntur neque
        eos doloribus!</div>
      <div>Porro, aliquam cumque? Repellendus laudantium non, blanditiis minima quibusdam nobis modi obcaecati at, suscipit molestiae. Laboriosam hic, maiores error eaque eveniet dolor mollitia, ratione quaerat veniam ab repellat culpa cumque?</div>
      <div>Dolore, nisi, perferendis. Placeat, quae? At provident non, temporibus eum perferendis maiores autem natus reprehenderit cum labore veniam recusandae, repellat tempora minima hic enim, debitis iure repellendus magni odio pariatur!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```